# Is there any code snippet for multiple file upload in c#?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, file-upload

I am already doing file upload in my application using `asp:fileUpload` but for single file upload now I need to convert that to multiple file upload

Is there any code to add in my existing uploading so that I just append?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create FileUpload controls dynamically in your page. so when user select ,for example, "upload more" link, another FileUpload control will be created.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link:

http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-multiple-file-uploads-in-aspnet-2

It shows how to add multiple files by adding new FileUpload controls.
Check video from minute 15 to see the final result.

[image]

At the bottom there is download of complete source code for C#/VB.

Answer (score 0):

```
   1.First put the Fileupload control in webform.

`<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="UploadImages" AllowMultiple="true" />`

   2.Put the Button and Label like this.

`<div>
    <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="UploadImages" AllowMultiple="true" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="uploadedFile" Text="Upload" OnClick="uploadFile_Click" />
    <asp:Label ID="listofuploadedfiles" runat="server" />
</div>`

3.Write the code in button click.

`protected void uploadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (UploadImages.HasFiles)
   {
       foreach (HttpPostedFile uploadedFile in UploadImages.PostedFiles)
       {
           uploadedFile.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"),
           uploadedFile.FileName)); listofuploadedfiles.Text += String.Format("{0}<br />", uploadedFile.FileName);
       }
   }
}`
```